# Confused how the expression like $ \nabla \cdot (\rho \textbf{v} \otimes \textbf{v}) \cdot \textbf{v} $ is expanded

Tags: derivatives, notation, vector-fields

I'm quite confused to figure out how this expression is expanded:

$
\nabla \cdot (\rho \textbf{v} \otimes \textbf{v}) \cdot \textbf{v}
\stackrel{?}{=}
\nabla \cdot [\rho (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v}) \textbf{v}] - 
\rho \textbf{v} \cdot [(\textbf{v} \cdot \nabla) \textbf{v}] 
$

$\rho$ is a scalar (density), $\textbf{v}$ is a vector (velocity).

from: [The Finite Volume Method in Computational Fluid Dynamics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-16874-6), page 60

**Edit**: Edited the title expression.

**Edit2**: Edited the right hand side

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: I don’t understand this. The left side seems to be a scalar and the right side a tensor. Are you sure you haven’t left out some dots on the right?

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry, I had a mistake. It is fixed now.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes. [The Finite Volume Method in Computational Fluid Dynamics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-16874-6), page 60

Comment: That makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward to expand out in [Cartesian index notation](http://web.iitd.ac.in/%7Epmvs/courses/mcl702/notation.pdf), using the product rule.  We have
\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot [\rho (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v}) \textbf{v}] 
&= \partial_i \left( \rho v_j v_j v_i \right) \\
&= \partial_i \left[ \left(\rho v_j v_i\right) v_j \right] \\
&= \rho v_j v_i \partial_i v_j + \left[\partial_i \left( \rho v_j v_i\right)\right] v_j \\
&= \rho v_j (v_i \partial_i v_j) + \left[\partial_i \left( \rho v_i v_j\right)\right] v_j \\
&= \rho \mathbf{v} \cdot \left[ (\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{v}\right] + \left[\nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{v} \otimes \mathbf{v}) \right]\cdot \mathbf{v}.
\end{align*}
The requested identity then follows immediately  by rearranging terms to the other side of the equation.

Comment: I'm in a progress of learning these stuff, now that you added the index notation, I can make my understanding more solid. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the identity

$$\nabla\cdot(A \otimes B) = (\nabla\cdot A)B + (A\cdot \nabla)B$$

see also: [Divergence of a tensor product](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360265/divergence-of-a-tensor-product)

Comment: strangely enough, I skimmed few books but never saw this relation. I'll play with that. Thank you!